# begin and end function for built-in array types

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to obtain a begin and one off the end pointer for a array of C-style strings (an array of pointers to char).
Why can't I call the begin and end function in order to obtain them?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
  char **first=std::begin(argv),**last=std::end(argv);
}
```

The compiler says that there's no matching function for my call to `begin(char**&)`

Comment: `char *argv[]` is adjusted to a pointer, `char **argv`, it only looks like an array

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki aren't all array converted to pointers? isn't that the whole point of conversion,to be able to pass "an array" to a function? so I0m passing a pointer to the begin and end function, shouldn't it work??

Comment: @Luca You can pass arrays to functions, via reference or pointer to array, just not by value. There is a difference between passing a pointer and an array, and `std::begin` needs an actual array.

Comment: Arrays are not converted to poiners. They are decayed to pointers, in approriate context. And you can easily pass an array to a function by wrapping it up in the struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that the compiler faces, is that it has no way to guess the size of argv, because it is not an array but a mere pointer.

Arrays can always be used as pointers, because an array can *decay* to a pointer to its first element. But the inverse is false! You can access the elements of an array through the array or through a pointer exactly the same, but the pointer and the array **are not the same**:

```
int a[5];
int *p = a; // p[i] and a[i] are now the same
size_t s = sizeof(a); // s is 5 * sizeof(int) 20 on common (32 bits) architectures
size_t s2 = sizeof(p);  // s2 is just sizeof(int *) 4 on 32 bits architecture
```

The *convention* says that argv has argc elements (and that argv[argc] is a null pointer). But `std::begin` and `std::end` do not make use of that convention. So do it *by hand* as a nice programmer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
  char **first=argv,**last=argv + argc;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The functions are applied to arrays.
As for the parameter `argv` then it actually has type `char **` because arrays passed by value are converted to pointers to their first elements and parameters are adjusted also to pointers.

You could write simply

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
   auto first = arg, last = argv + argc;
}
```

You could use the functions std::begin and std::end if your function declares the corresponding parameter as reference to array. For example

```
int MyMain( char * ( &argv )[10] )
{
   auto first = std::begin( argv ), last = std::end( argv );
}
```

Nevertheless it is the same if to write

```
   auto first = argv, last = argv + 10;
```

Here is how the functions are defined in the C++ Standard

```
template <class T, size_t N> T* begin(T (&array)[N]);
4 Returns: array.

template <class T, size_t N> T* end(T (&array)[N]);
5 Returns: array + N.
```